# Injecting properties in Spring library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to develop a library in Spring that need property from my application. My application get properties from a Spring Cloud Config Server.

So in my library, I have `@Configuration` annoted class.

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    @Value("${idwebservice.uri}")
    private String identificationWsUri;
}
```

I would like this property to be injected through my app after fetching the config server. My application is a Spring Boot application so I didn't implement the fetch of the config server myself.

I am sure that this property is well injected in my app but if I run the app, I've got this error:

`Could not resolve placeholder 'idwebservice.uri' in value "${idwebservice.uri}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible so I chose a different approach. My String is now an autowired String

```
@Autowired
private String identificationWsUri;
```

and in my app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  @Value("${idwebservice.uri"})
  String identificationWsUri;

  @Bean
  public String identificationWsUri() {
    return identificationWsUri;
  }
}
```

I prefered to answer to my question because I saw a similar question and maybe it will help some people struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm in the same situation and that helped